# Device does not boot

Tags: root-access, twrp, magisk

I have a OnePlus 6T i disabled my magisk hide and rebooted but it gets stuck in the animation of a red dot and two white dots revolving around it after sometime it boots in twrp.

i have uninstall.zip for magisk but the names on my sdcard are weird and when i try just putting the magisk uninstall via mtp among the crypted files using my pc it says "this device has either stopped working or been disconnected"

sideloading modules says magisk not installed

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also wipe data via TWRP.

This had happened to me as well, just select reboot in TWRP, then change current slot to `a` and then click system.

Comment: I have already done this and it has worked. thanks